# How to list json object?

Tags: json, perl

I have here dumped decoded json:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'V1' => {
                      'version' => '7.11.117.240',
                      'update' => '20131205',
          },
          'V2' => {
                      'version' => '8.0.1489.320',
                      'update' => '20131205',
          },
          'V3' => {
                      'version' => '12.0.163.0',
                      'update' => '20131205',
          },
          'V4' => {
                      'version' => '1.3.0.4562',
                      'update' => '20131129',
          },
          'V5' => {
                      'version' => '2.0.3.7',
                      'update' => '20131129',
          },
}
```

I want to list the json object inside the variable $VAR1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $version = $VAR1->{V1}{version};
```

to list all keys

```
my @vkeys = sort keys %$VAR1; # (V1, V2, V3, ..)
```